# Dynamics CRM 2013: Advanced Find FetchXML contains extra fields - why?

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013, microsoft-dynamics

I have two (related) questions:

I am having a puzzling problem with the Advanced Find function.  I set up the fields I require, both in the criteria and display section and then hit 'Download Fetchxml'.  What I end up with is fields that I never asked for.  For example, in my advanced find I asked for All Activities. I changed the results to show me only the Date Created, Activity Type, Subject and Regarding fields.  The (truncated) generated fetchXML looks like this:

```
<fetch version="1.0" output-format="xml-platform" mapping="logical" distinct="false">
<entity name="activitypointer">
<attribute name="activitytypecode" />
<attribute name="subject" />
<attribute name="activityid" />
<attribute name="instancetypecode" />
<attribute name="community" />
<attribute name="createdon" />
<attribute name="regardingobjectid" />
<order attribute="subject" descending="false" />
```

Why have those extra columns been included?  I didn't ask for the 'community' attribute anywhere, for example.

Second question:
What determines the output order of the fields?  I ran the above fetchXML through Fetch Tester 3000 (saved my life - thank you!) and the output table bears no relation to the order of the attributes in the xml.  This is true also when I use the fetchXML elsewhere.

Thanks in advance for your comments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The FetchXML returned by the button `Download Fetch XML` is generated internally and in some scenarios it returns extra columns (as you found), for example the primary key field of the entity is always added.

If you remove the additional attributes the FetchXML is still valid and can be executed.

Regarding the order, the tool you used (Fetch Tester 3000) display the fields inside the Table View ordered by their logicalname, inside Dynamics CRM the order of the attributes (subgrids and advanced find results) is defined using another XML definition known as `LayoutXML`

Comment: Thank you Guido - that makes sense.  Where can I find the LayoutXML file?  Because I am using this FetchXML to populate a data grid and its not coming out in the right order (the grid is based on a saved view and I am overwriting that viewdata with the results from dynamic FetchXML)

Comment: Hi Annie, you can find an example here: https://sliong.wordpress.com/2012/11/27/crm-2011-fetch-xml-an-layout-xml-for-link-entity-attribute/ however I need to warn you that modifying the layoutXml directly is not a supported customization, instead it's better to create new views inside your solution and use them for your subgrids